# Conditions and sensors that can be used for parachute deployment?

Tags: rockets, design, parachute

I'm looking for an explanation on ideal conditions/considered factors when a parachute is deployed (particularly in large competition rockets). Also what sensors should be used to measure these conditions so the parachute is released at an optimal situation?

Comment: What about a sensor for air pressure?